# How to upload multiple files using ASP.Net and Jquery...?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I have added the following javascripts in my aspx page...

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.MultiFile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I have also added the following code in the button click operation.

```
 HttpFileCollection hfc = Request.Files;
    for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
    {
        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            hpf.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("MyFiles") + "\\" + System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
            Response.Write("<b>File: </b>" + hpf.FileName + " <b>Size:</b> " + hpf.ContentLength + " <b>Type:</b> " + hpf.ContentType + " Uploaded Successfully <br/>");
        }
    }
```

The problem is I can't select mulltiple files...!!!

```
 <asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" class="multi" runat="server"/>
        <asp:Button ID="BtnUpload" runat="server" onclick="BtnUpload_Click" 
            Text="Upload" Width="105px" style="margin-top: 4px" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" id="StatusLabel" text="Upload status: " />
```

**http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/prathore/multiple-file-upload-using-jquery-in-Asp-Net-3-5/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make it multiple

```
<asp:FileUpload id="FileUploadControl" Multiple="Multiple" class="multi" runat="server"/>
```

Comment: Not working with IE8. Do I need to change the browser?

Comment: try without jquery just as regular call

Comment: Its working fine in Chrome. But I want to get the full path of the uploaded file, which is not possible in chrome.. Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: you need to add a call back

Comment: I have rectified the issue with chrome, but I can't get the full path of the uploaded file in Chrome.. how to solve it ?

Comment: i do not think you can it may be security constrain

Comment: I googled somehow got this link, @COLD https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=322952 the feature needs to be added in chrome... :(

Answer (score 0):

you should use AjaxFileUpload instead of file upload. This is an ajax control toolkit component. After that you create the event that will get each file. It alredy uploads and give to you the link that the file was uploaded.

```
    <%@ Register assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" tagprefix="asp" %>

  <ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1"
    ThrobberID="myThrobber"
    ContextKeys="Vinicius"
    AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg"
    MaximumNumberOfFiles=10
    runat="server"/>
```

Comment: `Could not load file or assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified. Unknown server tag 'ajaxToolkit:AjaxFileUpload'.`  Do I need to install something else ??

Comment: Yes you need to install the free ajax control tookit: https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/